# can't publish built-in actions via facebook app

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-apps, built-in

Hi I have been dealing with facebook apps and actions a lot lately and it doesn't seem to work for me. Now I hear that the social button for likes is about to migrate and I can't figure out how to even publish the like built-in action via the app I created (it's an app for websites).
The code to publish actions I have taken from here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/ and this is what they say:

```
 <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# [YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE]: 
              http://ogp.me/ns/apps/[YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE]#">
  <title>OG Tutorial App</title>
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="[YOUR_APP_ID]" /> 
  <meta property="og:type" content="[YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE]:recipe" /> 
  <meta property="og:title" content="Stuffed Cookies" /> 
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://fbwerks.com:8000/zhen/cookie.jpg" /> 
  other metatag properties etc. 
  <script type="text/javascript">
     function postCook()
   {
       FB.api(
       '/me/[YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE]:cook',
       'post',
       { recipe: 'http://fbwerks.com:8000/zhen/cookie.html' },
       function(response) {
         if (!response || response.error) {
          alert('Error occured');
         } else {
          alert('Cook was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
       }
      });
 }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
     FB.init({
       appId      : '[YOUR_APP_ID]', // App ID
       status     : true, // check login status
       cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
       });
     };

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
     (function(d){
      var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
      js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));
  </script>

 etc  etc.



 <form>
   <input type="button" value="Cook" onclick="postCook()" />
  </form>

   <fb:activity actions="[YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE]:cook"></fb:activity>
```

the fact is that I am not able to publish any action (returns an error) and of course my app has the actions I am trying to publish.  Doesn anyone have a clue? I'm not a professional developer but the ones I asked had no solution...
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem! 
Apparently the include function in PHP had the headed we used around the website conflict with the Facebook metadata. When I removed the headers and the "php start", all functions (comments included) were working. 
It still seem a peculiar issue though: apparently Facebook's API doesn't clear the cache, so now we have to create new pages to enable functions.  No way to have them in the current page locations.